# Make specific S3 bucket folder public with amplify override

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

make specific s3 folders publicly accessible. For example make `public/` accessible to all. `protected/` to be private.

Comment: Instead of blindly following one of the answers, may I ask you why you want to make a S3 bucket public ?  This is a bad security practice and I would not encourage you to do so.  Instead made individual files publicly accessible in a private bucket or use CloudFront in front of a private bucket to distribute your content publicly. When you use Amplify storage category - amplify automatically setup the permisisons for you. You should not overwrite these. https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/storage/overview/#s3-access-permissions

Comment: @SébastienStormacq Thank you for your suggestion on using CloudFront in front of s3. I'll make sure to add this. But for now, only `public/` folder is accessible outside. All other folders are kept private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do `amplify override storage`
2. The command creates a new `overrides.ts` file under `amplify/backend/storage/<resource-name>/`
3. Add a bucket policy as below in `override.ts`

```
import {AmplifyS3ResourceTemplate} from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper'

export function override(resources: AmplifyS3ResourceTemplate) {
  resources.addCfnResource(
    {
      type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy',
      properties: {
        Bucket: {
          Ref: 'S3Bucket',
        },
        PolicyDocument: {
          Statement: [
            {
              Action: ['s3:GetObject'],
              Effect: 'Allow',
              Resource: [
                {
                  'Fn::Sub': 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/public/*',
                },
              ],
              Principal: {
                AWS: ['*'],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    'MyS3BucketPolicy'
  )
}
```

Comment: you should add this before addCfnResource to work:

```
resources.s3Bucket.publicAccessBlockConfiguration = {
  blockPublicAcls: false
 };
```